# scale() from a high value to low distorts transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, scale

I am trying to make a transition so when I click I button two divs are scaled from a small circle to a large circle. Basically that looks something like this when expanded:

[image]

This has gone from `scale(1)` to `scale(20)` and `scale(25)`. When I click the button, the circles shrink with no problem. However, if I increase the scaling to for example `scale(40)` and `scale(45)` the result I get when clicking the button again (to shrink everything) looks like this:

[image]

So this happens right after I click. In this case I just have a `transition-delay` on so I could screenshot it.

The SCSS for the circles are like this:

```
.inner-circle-bg {
    display: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: $primaryRed;
    bottom: 35px;
    right: 35px;
    z-index: 999999;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    transition-delay: 4.1s;

    &.is-active {
        transform: scale(40);
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
        transition-delay: 0.1s;
    }
}

.outer-circle-bg {
    display: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: $primaryRedDark;
    bottom: 35px;
    right: 35px;
    z-index: 99999;
    transform: scale(1) ;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    transition-delay: 4.2s;

    &.is-active {
        transform:  scale(45) ;
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    }
}
```

And then I just have some JS to toggle the `is-active` state when a button is clicked.

So yeah, any idea what might be causing this, and if there is a way to fix it ?

EDIT:
I now have a working JSfiddle illustrating the problem (although with a hover effect instead):

https://jsfiddle.net/47znjxwo/

Comment: Why using scale instead of making the elements themselves larger through `width,height,border-radius`?

Comment: The basic idea was to attain the position. By scaling you know that it will expand from the center, whereas with width/height it will not (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xha3wjy0/) help you (works on hover)? It's simpler than what you did. If it helps you I will write this as an answer...

Comment: Could you provide a working code please ? You should not need 2 circles.

Comment: Sorry, yes, a JSfiddle has now been added.